# How to fade in/out div when scrolling past certain points on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fixed

How would you fade/in out divs that are ontop of each other, when the user scrolls to a certain point in the page? I have a fixed button that I want to change when the user reaches 6 different points on the page. In other words so that I can link to 6 different things from the same button at different points in the page say 1000px from the top, then 2000px and so on.

Each of the buttons have different words in them so I just want each button to fade in after the next when the correct number of px is reached when scrolling.

html

`<div class="buttonOne">button one</div>`
`<div class="buttonTwo">button two</div>`
`<div class="buttonThree">button three</div>`

css

`.buttonOne, .buttonTwo, .buttonThree {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 3em;
}`

All positioned fixed and on top of each other. Each one should fade in at 100px, 200px, 300px and so on?

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() === 10){
   $('.element').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/vV7Wd/2/

To add more use:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "number of pixels") {
        if ($('"button plus number"').css('display') === 'none') {
            $('"button plus number"').fadeIn('slow');
            $('"button plus number"').prev().fadeOut();
            $('"button plus number"').next().fadeOut();
        }
    }
```

Elements in double quotes are up to you to set

Example (for number 4):

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 400) {
            if ($('button4').css('display') === 'none') {
                $('button4').fadeIn('slow');
                $('button4').prev().fadeOut();
                $('button4').next().fadeOut();
            }
        }
```

Or use a for loop:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (i * 100)) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() <= ((i * 100) + 100)) {
                $('.button' + i).fadeIn('slow');
                $('.button' + i).prev().fadeOut();
                $('.button' + i).next().fadeOut();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The for loop is better as it means that you only have to implement one thing everytime you add one which is the condition in the for loop

Comment: So if each of my buttons had the class buttonOne buttonTwo and so on I would type...

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() === 10){
   $('.buttonOne').fadeout();
}
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() === 10){
   $('.buttonTwo').fadeout();
}
});

Comment: Do you want them all to fadeOut at the same time or at different scroll points

Comment: Have you got a js file

Comment: At different scroll points so it would start with button one then at say 200px down button two would fade in then at 400px down button 3 would fade in. And i'm just doing it in the head of the document.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but that doesn't seem to work. I need the buttons to be fixed ontop of eachother and then when you scroll and reach a certain number of pixels the 2nd button appears and so on?

Comment: ok so you want some button that are fixed on a sidebar and then when you scroll to certainer points they appear???

Comment: This is almost there except they aren't in a side bar and when one fades in the one previous should disappear. Sorry if I'm not explaining it clearly

Comment: I think this is what you want though it doesn't have to be in a sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/vV7Wd/3/

Comment: What you do is create the button and then add the jquery which I have posted above in an update

Comment: This is what I want for the first 3 but how to i continue for the final 3 at the moment is it telling it to repeat 2 and 3? I also now have a problem in that when I wrap an <a> link around my button which is an <img> the jQuery doesn't work. I'm really sorry about this.

Comment: Ok I have managed to get it working going downwards but if you scroll back up it gets stuck on 4 for some reason is there a way to reverse it for scrolling back to the top?

Comment: Yes will write a snippet for you

Comment: Damn my fiddle is frozen

Comment: Aha found a way to do it easily here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/vV7Wd/4/

Comment: In the fiddle try adding a button in the sidebar with a class of button 5

Comment: Really sorry but I'm completely lost I can't understand how your latest code it working, may take me a while to understand it

Comment: Do you want me to explain or do you know what a for loop is?

Comment: I've got that working but how would I change the different px numbers where it changes?

Comment: Change it at the point where it says `(i * 100)` and `((i * 100) + 100)` and to change it ou need to change the `100` to what you want but make sure you do it for both

Comment: Also for some reason as I scroll down before the first button changes its making one of my <p> tags fade out :S

Comment: I recommend doing it without animations otherwise it is a bit glitchy unless the scroll points are at least 7 or 8 hundred apart